# Gnosis Safe create safe app template failing

Tags: nodejs, gnosis-safe, npm, safe-apps-sdk

I am  trying to run `npx create-react-app my-safe-app --template @gnosis.pm/cra-template-safe-app` but I am getting this error.

> I'm just following the instructions at https://github.com/safe-global/safe-apps-sdk/tree/master/packages/cra-template-safe-app

Please advise :)

[image: I tried to bootstrap a safe app and getting this error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a **mismatch version** with *@testing-library/@react13.4.0* and *my-safe-app@0.1.0* when installing, you should try upgrade the version of everything to latest and try it again.

> Other option could be upgrade your version  of `nodejs`.

> In the worst case, you can run the installation ignoring outdated packages, try with the flags --legacy-peer-deps.

```bash
$ npx create-react-app my-safe-app --template @gnosis.pm/cra-template-safe-app --legacy-peer-deps
```

Comment: Ok that got me to the next error... now it's giving me trouble because react is TOO up to date? Error here: https://imgur.com/a/yhHok7k

Comment: Delete node modules and package-lock.json and then run npm install again, it seems you have node_modules mismatching new version with old version of some dependencies, try it and let me know, because it is the issue. @Brentable

Answer (score 1):

Hi I'm also running into the same issue and receive the same output when attempting to run

```
$ npx create-react-app my-safe-app --template @gnosis.pm/cra-template-safe-app --legacy-peer-deps
```

It appears there is potentially an issue with the version here.

https://github.com/safe-global/safe-apps-sdk/blob/master/packages/cra-template-safe-app/template.json#L15

see https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/1121#issuecomment-1242335979 for example. Let me know your thoughts, thanks!

Update: The following works.

1. `npx create-react-app drain-safe --template @gnosis.pm/cra-template-safe-app@4.1.1`
2. Remove related font code here https://github.com/safe-global/safe-apps-sdk/pull/388/files#diff-68c12a430f865c61eee3d09fe68f486c048af196cf7a2b347f0c5105c94f01c8L1-L2.
3. `npm start` (or yarn)